# Roots of polynomial in terms of "odd radicals"

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm trying to show that it is not possible to find a formula for the roots of $x²-S_1x+S_2$ only in terms of odd radicals in $C(x,y)$.

Here $S_1$ and $S_2$ are the symmetric polynomials in terms of the roots, i.e., $S_1=x_1+x_2$ and $S_2=x_1x_2$ and $C(x,y)$ is the fraction field.

The general idea is based on Ruffini's tests (which is where I'm pretty lost).